# iPhone 6+ (Wrong scale?)

Tags: ios, avcapturesession, iphone-6-plus, avcapturedevice, uiscreen

I have an iOS app using the camera to take pictures.
It uses a path(`CGPath`) drawn on the screen (for example a rectangle), and it takes a photo within that path. The app supports only portrait orientation.

For that to happen I use: `AVCaptureSession`, `AVCaptureStillImageOutput`, `AVCaptureDevice`, `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer`
(I guess all familiar to developers making this kind of apps).

My code uses `UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds` and `UIScreen.mainScreen().scale` to adapt do various devices and do its job.

It all goes fine(on iPhone 5, iPhone 6), until I try the app on an iPhone 6+ (running iOS 9.3.1) and see that something is wrong.
The picture taken is not layed out in the right place anymore.

I had someone try on an iPhone 6+, and by putting an appropriate message I was able to confirm that (`UIScreen.mainScreen().scale`) is what it shoud be: 3.0.
I have put the proper size launch images(640 × 960, 640 × 1136, 750 × 1334, 1242 × 2208) in the project.
So what could be the problem?

Comment: If you have a git I will take a look on 6+

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In case someone else has the same issue. Here is what made things go wrong for me:

I was naming a file : xyz@2x.png.

When UIScreen.mainScreen().scale == 3.0 (case of an iPhone 6+)
it has to be named : xyz@3x.png.

Comment: You don't have to use the 2x and 3x extensions for your images - I never use them, it's so much hassle. Just grab the biggest image and let the device scale it down for you, e.g. bigImage.png put in a  UIImageView with contentMode AspectFill. Less headache.

Comment: I don't know if I have to. But what I know is when I was naming the file x.@2x.png in all cases, there was a bug and when I name according to the value of UIScreen.mainScreen().scale it works. And letting the device scale it is not what you want in all possible cases. Same you do not necessarily have several images to choose the biggest. Anyway if as you say, you can avoid to use several extension, that is the best.

Answer (score 0):

I use the code below in an app, it works on 6+.

The code starts a AVCaptureSession, pulling video input from the device's camera.

As it does so, it continuously updates the runImage var, from the captureOutput delegate function.

When the user wants to take a picture, the takePhoto method is called. This method creates a temporary UIImageview and feeds the runImage into it. This temp UIImageView is then used to draw another variable called currentImage to the scale of the device.

The currentImage, in my case, is square, matching the previewHolder frame, but I suppose you can make anything you want.

Declare these:

```
AVCaptureDevice * device;
AVCaptureDeviceInput * input;
AVCaptureVideoDataOutput * output;
AVCaptureSession * session;
AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer * preview;
AVCaptureConnection * connection;
UIImage * runImage;
```

Load scanner:

```
-(void)loadScanner 
{

    device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
    input = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:device error:nil];
    output = [AVCaptureVideoDataOutput new];
    session = [AVCaptureSession new];

    [session setSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto];
    [session addInput:input];
    [session addOutput:output];

    [output setSampleBufferDelegate:self queue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
    [output setVideoSettings:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA] forKey:(id)kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey]];

    preview = [AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer layerWithSession:session];
    preview.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;
    preview.frame = previewHolder.bounds;

    connection = preview.connection;
    [connection setVideoOrientation:AVCaptureVideoOrientationPortrait];
    [previewHolder.layer insertSublayer:preview atIndex:0];

}
```

Ongoing image capture, updates runImage var.

```
-(void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection 
{

    runImage = [self imageForBuffer:sampleBuffer];

}
```

Related to above.

```
-(UIImage *)imageForBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer 
{

    CVImageBufferRef imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);
    CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(imageBuffer, 0);
    void *baseAddress = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(imageBuffer);
    size_t bytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(imageBuffer);
    size_t width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(imageBuffer);
    size_t height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(imageBuffer);
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(baseAddress, width, height, 8, bytesPerRow, colorSpace, kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little | kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);
    CGImageRef quartzImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
    CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(imageBuffer,0);
    CGContextRelease(context);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:quartzImage];
    CGImageRelease(quartzImage);

    UIImage * rotated = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:image.CGImage scale:1.0 orientation:UIImageOrientationRight];

    return rotated;
}
```

On take photo:

```
-(void)takePhoto 
{

    UIImageView * temp = [UIImageView new];
    temp.frame = previewHolder.frame;
    temp.image = runImage;
    temp.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
    temp.clipsToBounds = true;
    [self.view addSubview:temp];

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(temp.bounds.size, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
    [temp drawViewHierarchyInRect:temp.bounds afterScreenUpdates:YES];
    currentImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    [temp removeFromSuperview];

    //further code...

}
```

Comment: Why what does your code do? Please provide a description to your code and why it will solve the users issue.

Comment: @Popeye updated with further explanation; whether it helps the user I don't know that it will, but I haven't seen any 6+ issues with it (if it is even an issue, we can't say for sure).

Comment: I am looking at your code. Trying to see how it differs from mine.
Other than mine being in Swift, I can already see a few variations.
You use `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput`, I use `AVCaptureStillImageOutput`;
you use `AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto`, I use `AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh` ..etc..
I suppose it shouldn’t be the issue. On the other hand `AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill` and `AVCaptureVideoOrientationPortrait` that you use and I don’t may make a difference.
For `imageForBuffer` I use code I found here: developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/
I still must look further.

Comment: I may isolate and upload some relevant code of mine. Though as I wrote in my post, since it is working on other phones, I strongly suspect that the value returned by UIScreen.mainScreen().scale on iPhone 6+ is the problem, rather than my code.

Comment: yep, if it's isolated to one device type, the code is probably good, although isn't there something to do with iPhone6+ downsampling: http://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/iphone-6-screens-demystified

Comment: Thanks, I read the document. So you think that I may well have, not only good code, but even the UIScreen.mainScreen().scale may also be good on iPhone 6+. I am just forgetting this "downsampling step"?
Forgive me and tell me if I misunderstand. In case this is indeed what you mean, where is in the code above (in ObjectivC) the part taking care of this extra step for iPhone 6+?

Comment: I think the mainScreen().scale is good, but I avoid the whole issue, because the video is constantly updating runImage, which has AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill applied to it, then I put that in an imageView also with aspectFill applied, and capture that. I don't think the mainScreen().scale comes into it, beyond rendering at the last stage. Did you try the above appraoch with the AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill applied?

Comment: @JohnnyRockex I have changed my post, to say that I know UIScreen.mainScreen().scale has the right value on iPhone 6+.
That lives me puzzled about my problem.